# Themes and Icons changed: can't change back

Tags: unity, themes, icons

Today, all of a sudden, my theme and my icons reset to the default style. The funny thing is, this didn’t happen everywhere. The icons in System Settings are as they were before; the Unity Launchbar has the default icons. When I start the File Explorer (Nautilus) my icons are the default ones; when I start Nautilus with sudo from terminal, the icons I have chosen reappear (but only in this window).

What happened?

If I type `compiz --replace`, everything turns back to my theme/iconset but the Unity Launch bar has none of my shortcuts.

Also, this error comes up:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:217 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -- full D-Bus introspection will not be available
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:103 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.dash.gsettingsscopereader GSettingsScopes.cpp:108 Error fetching protocol metadata for scope: social.scope : Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-01-20 12:13:52 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
```

Comment: What happens when you try to change icons/themes in unity-tweak-tool?

Comment: Almost nothing. The Theme seems to change, but only for some windows. Changing the Icons does not change them at all, except for the Icons in the System Settings and the Icons in the TopBar. 

Changing the Icons to a Ubuntu-mono-light or Whiteglass seems to yield errors because some Icons at the top are changed to an Error Icon.
After typing compiz --replace, Icon changing seems to work.
But not having shortcuts and having to type this everytime and not closing the terminal seems not like a solution to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it (at least it seems like a fix).

After typing `compiz --replace`, most of the Unity desktop was like it should be but some things were still strange and I would have to type this command everytime I started Ubuntu.
There seems to be a problem with the config so with the desktop being "normal" again I first typed
`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
to reset the config and then
`setsid unity`
to restart the desktop. I logged out, then back in and everything was back to normal, all the icons were as they should be, the theme was like it should be - problem solved.